# How can I prevent a componentDidMount from running, before my webservice call finishes

Tags: reactjs, react-native, promise, fetch

When app starts,  SplashScreen comes. Behind splashScreen I want to get username and password from cache and then call webservice.
But when I get data from cache like `AsyncStorage.getItem('myKey')` which is in `componentWillMount`, it starts render. It doesn't let `componentWillMount` finish.

My Big problem is that `componentDidMount` starts before my `controlallMeth` methods finishes. Due to that, app crashes in that situation. How can I fix this issue?
Here is my code:

*I get username and password from app cache and call webservice like this:*

```
 componentWillMount(){
      AsyncStorage.getItem('myKey').then(value => {
        let valuePrsed = JSON.parse(value);
        if(valuePrsed.username != null && valuePrsed.password != null)
        {
            this.setState({username: valuePrsed.username, password: valuePrsed.password});
            this.controlallMeth(); // call webservice
        }
      })
    }
```

*Here is method where I call webservice:*

```
controlallMeth(){
        let collection={}
        collection.username = this.state.username,
        collection.password = this.state.password

        fetch('url', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: new Headers({
                          Accept: 'application/json',
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json', // <-- Specifying the Content-Type
                }),
            body: JSON.stringify(collection) // <-- Post parameters
            })
            .then((response) => response.text())
            .then(leaders => {

                    this.setState({PersonalInfo: leaders});

            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
            });
    }
```

*And here is componentDidMount*

```
 componentDidMount() {

      StatusBar.setHidden(true);
        this.setState({ fadeAnim: new Animated.Value(0) },
        () => {
          Animated.timing(          // Animate over time
            this.state.fadeAnim, // The animated value to drive
            {
              toValue: 1,           // Animate to opacity: 1 (opaque)
              duration: 3000,
            }
          ).start(() => {
              if(this.state.values != null)
              {
                console.log("go page1");
                  this.props.navigation.navigate('Page1',{datas: this.state.PersonalInfo});
              }
              else{
                this.props.navigation.navigate('login');
              }
          })
        })              // Starts the animation
    }
```

Comment: This is rather simple, you *have to use two components*. The parent will load the data and then display the child component only when the data is loaded. The whole premise of somehow delaying `componentDidMount` is flawed and will not work. However, looking into your code, it doesn't even seem like you want to do something that is supposed to be in a component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the `componentWillMount` is deprecated now, it's better not to use it. You can get your cached values inside `constructor` or `componentDidMount` method

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  StatusBar.setHidden(true);

  AsyncStorage.getItem('myKey').then(value => {
    let valuePrsed = JSON.parse(value);
    if(valuePrsed.username != null && valuePrsed.password != null)
    {
      this.setState({username: valuePrsed.username, password: valuePrsed.password});
      this.controlAllMeth(); // call webservice
    }
  });
}
```

For making sure that the animateing and fetching method completely finish before going to other screen, you can use `Promise.all`:

```
controlAllMeth() {
  Promise.all([this.callFetch(), this.startAnim()])
    .then(([fetchResponse, animResponse]) => {
      this.setState({PersonalInfo: fetchResponse.text()});

      if(this.state.values != null)
      {
        console.log("go page1");
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Page1',{datas: this.state.PersonalInfo});
      }
      else{
        this.props.navigation.navigate('login');
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {

    });
}

callFetch() {
  let collection={}
  collection.username = this.state.username,
  collection.password = this.state.password

  return fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: new Headers({
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json', // <-- Specifying the Content-Type
    }),
    body: JSON.stringify(collection) // <-- Post parameters
    }
  );
}

startAnim() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.setState({ fadeAnim: new Animated.Value(0) },
      () => {
        Animated.timing(          // Animate over time
          this.state.fadeAnim, // The animated value to drive
          {
            toValue: 1,           // Animate to opacity: 1 (opaque)
            duration: 3000,
          }
        ).start(() => {
          resolve();
        })
      });              // Starts the animation  
  });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You might wanna use async method here, as controlallMeth an async call. Making the whole process to wait making sure you do the fetch request then move on.

```
async componentWillMount(){
      AsyncStorage.getItem('myKey').then(value => {
        let valuePrsed = JSON.parse(value);
        if(valuePrsed.username != null && valuePrsed.password != null)
        {
            this.setState({username: valuePrsed.username, password: valuePrsed.password});
          await this.controlallMeth(); //I am assuming you did a typo here this.controlall();
        }
      })
    }
 controlallMeth = async() => {
        let collection={}
        collection.username = this.state.username,
        collection.password = this.state.password

        const res = await fetch('url', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: new Headers({
                          Accept: 'application/json',
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json', // <-- Specifying the Content-Type
                }),
            body: JSON.stringify(collection) // <-- Post parameters
            })
            const leaders = await res.text();
            this.setState({PersonalInfo: leaders});
    }
```

Though it's not recommended to have async calls in `componentWillMount` so you might wanan switch to `componentDidMount`